# session_destroy() is executed but session is alive in Php

Tags: php, session

I want to enable only one session is alive. So I store flag value like 0 and 1 on database. when status is 1 it should delete previous session and create a new session and update database flag value to 0 then insert a new row with status = 1. I it is 0 then it should create new session.
Here is my code.

```
$query = 'select state FROM ig_gateway ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;';
                   
$checkSession =DB::query($query);
$checkSession = $checkSession[0];
                    
if($checkSession['state'] == 1){
 //   echo "<script>$('#msgModal').modal('show');$('#msgModal .modal-title').text('Can not Login');$('#msgModal .modal-body p').html('<p>Session in Use. So you cannot login.</p>');</script>";   

   $logoutid = DB::query("select id from ig_gateway order by id desc limit 1;");
   $id= $logoutid[0];
   $query = "update ig_gateway set state = '0' where id = '".$id['id']."';";    
   DB::query($query);
 
}
                   
session_unset();
session_destroy();
session_regenerate_id(true);

 DB::insert("ig_gateway", array("user_info" => $user["id"], "date" => date("d/m/Y"), "time" => date("H:i:s"), "state" => 1, "access_code" => $access_code));      
                       
                        
  session_start();
  $_SESSION["id"] = encrypt($user["id"]); 
  $_SESSION["usr"] = encrypt($_POST["username"]);
  $_SESSION["pass"] = encrypt($_POST["password"]);
  $_SESSION["access_code"] = $access_code;
  $_SESSION["db"] = encrypt($user["db"]);
  redirect("/");
```

I have opened the application in laptop then opens and insert new status value with 1 into the database. Next minute I opened it in mobile browser, it update a previous session status value to 0 (laptop's session) and insert new row with status is 1. Then If I refresh a laptop browser , it loads page . It doesn't go to login page and session is alive. I want to destroy session of application which is opened in laptp.How to do it? please help me...

Comment: What do you want to achieve? "Only one session is alive" sounds pretty strange?

Comment: Not you issue, but why do you need the password in the session? You also should parameterize your query.

Comment: user login in one device then he attempts to log in on another device, in that time I have to destroy first session and update database then new session has to be started on second device

Comment: But here the problem is first opened session is not destroyed. only database is updated. both sessions are alive. I want to terminate first session.

Comment: @user3783243,when user log in I just store the user details in session variable. so that I used.

Comment: Why not remove the session data for that user from the table when another login happens?

Comment: @NicoHaase, I didn't store any session data on database side. I store only a flag value in database. When new session is created that time I store the credentials given by user in Session variable.

Comment: Then why not store any flag for the session in the database? You cannot invalidate another session for the same user, unless you store any information about that session anywhere else than on the client

Comment: accesscode in session variable is stored in database table.

Comment: if($checkSession['state'] == 1){
               $logoutid = DB::query("select id from ig_gateway order by id desc limit 1;");
    $id= $logoutid[0];
$last_session_id = DB::query("select session_id from ig_gateway WHERE state = 1 order by id desc limit 1");
$last_session_id = $last_session_id[0][session_id];
    $query = "update ig_gateway set state = '0' where id = '".$id['id']."';";    
    DB::query($query);
    session_id($last_session_id);
session_start();
session_destroy();
session_commit();
   Old session is not destroyed. Please help me..

Comment: Please add all details to your question by editing it. Also, that query is widely open for SQL injection